# Dynamic URL to the link tag

Tags: url, .net-4.0, hyperlink, asp.net-4.0

I have coding like this in my asp.net web form application [asp.net 4.0]

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
    <% foreach (var item in CustomerOrderList())
     { %>
      <li> Order Id:<a href="#" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"><%= item.idOrder%> </a> 
         <table >
             <tr>
                <td >
                Total Price: <%= item.totalPrice%> || 
                </td>
                <td >
                Requested Date: <%= Convert.ToDateTime(item.reqDate) %>
                </td>

           </tr>
         </table>

      </li> 
    <% } %>

  </ul>
```

at href I want to generate the url like this

href="somepage.aspx?Id= item.Id"

Means "somepage.aspx?Id=" this will be constant and only querystring parameter will be changed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='somepage.aspx?Id=<%= item.id%>' style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;"><%= item.idOrder%> </a>
```